# Does Notepad convert an ANSI file to Unicode before displaying it?

Tags: winapi, unicode, ansi, notepad

If the Notepad Edit control is Unicode, so when loading an ANSI file does Notepad first convert its contents to Unicode and then displays it, or does Notepad have two memory buffers (one for ANSI and one for Unicode)?

Comment: The Win32 `SetWindowText` function converts the provided string into the character set expected by the window.  So it probably is Windows itself, not Notepad, doing the conversion.

Comment: So can I assume that when notepad loads an ANSI file it calls SetWindowTextA(), and when loading a Unicode file it calls SetWindowTextW()?

Comment: Nope, I didn't say that, because I don't have the source code to check it.  But it would be the easiest thing to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, what I needed to know is whether the text will eventually be represented in memory as Unicode which it does.

Comment: A Unicode "EDIT" control has a Unicode text buffer (only).

Comment: Why does it matter? The accessibility interface returns Unicode either way.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Notepad does a conversion, which is evident by the fact that it calls `IsTextUnicode()` to discover the text's encoding when no BOM is present, and thus suffers from the infamous [Bush hid the facts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts) bug, which is discussed on Raymond Chen's blog:

[Some files come up strange in Notepad](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/03/24/95235.aspx)

[The Notepad file encoding problem, redux](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/17/2158334.aspx)

Comment: I'm not sure what this allegedly proves.  We already knew that Notepad handles both single-byte and Unicode text files.  And still have no idea where the conversion takes place -- in notepad.exe (very unlikely), in a WinAPI function called directly by notepad.exe, or in a WinAPI function called indirectly, because notepad uses another component that calls a conversion function.

Comment: If Notepad is using a Unicode Edit control, it can only handle UTF-16. If the source file is not already UTF-16, Notepad has to convert to UTF-16 before it can populate the Edit control. If there is no BOM present, it uses `IsTextUnicode()` to determine if the text is ANSI or UTF-16. When `IsTextUnicode()` mis-diagnoses, Notepad ends up displaying ANSI text as if it were UTF-16, causing the "Bush" error. It does not matter if Notepad uses `SetWindowTextA()` to let Windows to the conversion, converts manually using MultiByteToWideChar(), or uses a 3rd party library. The end result is the same.

Comment: Notepad does not create an ANSI Edit control for ANSI text, and a Unicode Edit control for UTF-16 text.  That would be overkill. Everything in Windows is UTF-16 nowadays.